# Can't Customize ActiveRecord Error Message Header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For some reason, I can successfully customize the specific error messages in ActiveRecord, but I can't seem to change the error message header.

```
en:
   activerecord:
    errors:
      template:
        header: 
          one: "Custom message goes here. 1 error prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
          other: "Customer message goes here. %{count} errors prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
      messages:
        blank: "custom :blank message goes here"
    models:
      complaint: "Complaint"
    attributes:
      complaint: 
        city: "Custom city name"
        neighborhood: "Custom neighborhood name"
```

If I leave city and neighborhood blank, I get the following error message:

> **2 errors prohibited this complaint from being saved:**
>
> - Custom city name custom :blank message goes here
> - Custom neighborhood name custom :blank message goes here

For some reason the actual error messages are changed, but the error header is not. In debugging, I changed the YML file to the following, which did not change the default message:

```
en:
    activerecord:
      errors:
        template:
          header:
            one: "blah"
            other: "blah blah"
          body: "blah blah blah"
```

Does anyone have any idea why this simple change is not working? The only thing I can think of is that the "header" needs to be contextual to the model. Not sure.

References that I used:

[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models][1]
[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the error message header is actually hard-coded starting in Rails 3.0. From a resource I found:

> Look at the app/views/users/_form.html.erb generated by scaffold. The
>   error message is hard coded. So, changing the locale file has no
>   effect.
>
> Actually, the Rails 3.0 does not utilize the
>   activerecord.errors.template.header translation. In the Rails 2.x,
>   this translation is used in the error_messages method of the form
>   builder, but this method is deprecated and extracted as a plugin.
>
> If you are curious, do the following:
>
> -rails plugin install git://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form.git
>
> -Edit app/views/_form.html.erb as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Source https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/issues/118

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a wrong spacing in your example. Please, check that there's always two spaces as indentation.

If that doesn't fix the problem, check the version of Rails that you're using:

**Rails 2.3 example**

```
pt:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      template:
        header:
          one: "não foi possível guardar este %{model} porque encontramos um erro"
          other: "não foi possível guardar este %{model} porque encontramos%{count} erros"
        # The variable :count is also available
        body: "Encontramos problemas nos seguintes campos:"

      # The values :model: "attribute and :value are always available for interpolation
      # The value :count is available when applicable. Can be used for pluralization.
      messages:
        inclusion: "não esta incluído na lista"
        exclusion: "está reservado"
        invalid: "não é válido"
```

**Rails 3 example**

```
es:
  errors: &errors
    format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'
    messages:
      ...
      taken: ya está en uso
      too_long: es demasiado largo (%{count} caracteres máximo)
      too_short: es demasiado corto (%{count} caracteres mínimo)
      wrong_length: no tiene la longitud correcta (%{count} caracteres exactos)
    template:
      body: ! 'Se encontraron problemas con los siguientes campos:'
      header:
        one: No se pudo guardar este/a %{model} porque se encontró 1 error
        other: No se pudo guardar este/a %{model} porque se encontraron %{count} errores
  activemodel:
    errors:
      <<: *errors
  activerecord:
    errors:
      <<: *errors
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your examples. The spaces are just a copy-and-paste error from writing the post. In my code, the spacing is correct. I tried your example with the following code, but the error header still did not change: `  errors: &errors
    messages:
      blank: "Please fill out this field."
    template:
      header:
        one: "An error prevented this %{model} from being saved"
        other: "%{count} errors prevented this %{model} from being saved."
  activemodel:
    errors:
      <<: *errors
  activerecord:
    errors:
      <<: *errors`

Comment: If you change your locale in application controller to any not existing in your config/locales folder, you'll a "missing locale" message with a hint of the right path

Comment: That's a great idea. I tried it, and interestingly, all of the messages showed the missing path except the error header, which still displayed "1 error prohibited this complaint from being saved:"! It seems that rails isn't even reading the YML files for that string. So weird! Thank you again for your help! I'm going to keep trying to solve this.